# How to add viewmodel object into cookies using angularjs 2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, npm

Im trying to add viewmodel objects into cookie using angularjs2. I have tried a lot, but didn't worked yet. I

```
private setCookie(name: string, value: any, expireDays: number, path: string = "") {
    let d: Date = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expireDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    let expires: string = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = name +`enter code here` "=" + value + "; " + expires + (path.length > 0 ? "; path=" + path : "");
}
```

I have tried like this,

```
this.setCookie("CookieConstant", ViewModel, 1);
```

When I'm checking cookie value in the browser I can see only [Object Object]. Can anyone help me. I'm new to angular 2

Comment: What do you expect to see? If `ViewModel` is an object, then the cookie will contain the text `[object Object]`, in addition to other `"CookieConstant"` because when you append an `object` to a `string`, that object is converted into a `string` that it may be so appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible in angular 2, you better to set single value in the cookie, based on that value you can generate the results. Cookies is for setting small values, so its better to avoid setting viewmodel objects into cookies. Try to set single value.